# Importing files in different directories in Python

Tags: python, python-import, directory-structure, relative-import

I have a directory structure like this:

```
dir/
   frontend.py
   dir1/main.py
   dir2/backend.py
```

- How do I import backend in main in Python?
- How do I import frontend in main in Python?

Have tried all the answers on Stackoverflow. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need to have __init__.py file in dir1 and dir2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: I have done that too. Does not help me in importing modules from the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **only one rule** when it comes to importing files in a Python project.

You have to import the package `relative` to the `directory` from where the project is run.

For example in the question `main.py` should have something like this:

```
from dir.frontend import *
from dir.dir2.backend import *
```

But then you'll have to have something like `main.py` under `dir/` which imports `dir/dir1/main.py`  and then run `python main.py`.

So, try to keep the `main.py` always in the `head directory` so you don't have to worry about such a situation as above.

**ONLY ONE RULE:** `Everything has to be imported relatively to the directory from where the project is run.`

Answer (score 1):

In any folder from which you want to import source files you need to have existing **init**.py file.

I would advise structure like:

```
dir/
   main.py
   dir1/frontend.py
   dir1/__init__.py
   dir2/backend.py
   dir2/__init__.py
```

Then you import them in following fashion (in main.py):

```
import dir1.frontend
import dir2.backend
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of such a structure. I really wanted to know how to import modules from the parent directory and in the sub-directories within the parent directory. It's not possible always to structure the directories in the way that you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks mate! But that did not help either. Tried adding my parent directory to PYTHONPATH also. Did not work for me. I cannot import modules from the parent directory.

Comment: As long as I run main.py from dir/ (like python ./dir1/main.py) I achieve proper results (both modules imported) with: `import frontend`, 
`import dir2.backend`. If it has to be run from dir1/ (python ./main.py) then I have no idea.

Comment: I've seen a "hacky" solution import all needed modules in the initial __init__.py of each subfolder, then the __init__.py of the main module would import each of those.

Comment: @jo9k I badly want to figure out the imports in Python. The structure you provided works fine always. I was aware of that. There should be a mechanism to import anything from anywhere and run from anywhere, I believe.

Comment: From where do you run your script? If you run it from parent directory, like "python ./dir1/main.py" in console, then `import frontend`, `import dir2.backend` works in main. You can always have your console run in parent directory so it should work for you.

Comment: I realise this directory structure. However, as I mentioned earlier that it is not always possible to maintain that structure. Hence, I was looking for a way to import modules from the parent directory. I want to know how that can be done, if it's possible.